# How cURL works with file

Tags: php, curl

I have a problem I have to access an URL `cURL` only I get the message:

> 404 Not Found

---

whereas when I write folowing command it works. I do not understand,

```
curl "http://stream.song365.co/h/2747175/Arctic%20Monkeys%20-%20R%20U%20Mine%3F_(song365.cc).mp3"
```

Here is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://stream.song365.co/h/2747175/Arctic%20Monkeys%20-%20R%20U%20Mine%3F_(song365.cc).mp3');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,'https://www.song365.co/');
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $output;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
$url = "http://stream.song365.co/h/2747175/Arctic%20Monkeys%20-%20R%20U%20Mine%3F_(song365.cc).mp3";
$fp = fopen (dirname(__FILE__) . '/file.mp3', 'w+'); // where the file will be downloaded
$ch = curl_init(str_replace(" ","%20",$url)); // replace the url spaces with %20
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); // write curl response to file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,'http://www.song365.co/');
curl_exec($ch); // get curl response
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```